# adding extra field to django-registration using signals

Tags: django, django-registration

I want to add a locale selection to the default django-registration. I tried to follow this tutorial from [dmitko](http://dmitko.ru/?p=546). The form shows up correctly but the additional data (locale) is not saved.

**I defined a custom model:**

```
class AnymalsProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    locale = models.CharField(max_length=2)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %s' % (self.user, self.locale)
```

and the form:

```
from models import AnymalsProfile
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormTermsOfService

class UserRegistrationForm(RegistrationFormTermsOfService):
    locale = forms.CharField(max_length=3, widget=forms.Select(choices=LOCALE_CHOICES),label='Language:')
```

The fields show up correctly, but the locale data (profile) is not saved. I assume that the regbackend.py is my problem:

```
from anysite.models import AnymalsProfile

def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        data = AnymalsProfile(user=user)
        data.locale = form.cleaned_data["locale"]
        data.save()

from registration.signals import user_registered
user_registered.connect(user_created)
```

*** EDIT ***
I tried moving into production - just for a test - and it raised some errors. I altered the code, but still the profile is not saved. Here is what I tried:

```
from anysite.models import AnymalsProfile
from anysite.forms import UserRegistrationForm

def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                ProfileData = form.cleaned_data
                profile = AnymalsProfile(
                user = user.id,
                locale = ProfileData["locale"]
                        )
                profile.save()

from registration.signals import user_registered
user_registered.connect(user_created)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have somewhere in your code `import regbackend`. That should be done in order to the following strings being executed.

```
from registration.signals import user_registered
user_registered.connect(user_created)
```

I my example I have `import regbackend` in `urls.py`. Do you have this line as well?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, I've got that imported. I tried something else, shown above.

Comment: So, if you sure that user_created is called but for some reason it does not save additional data - use logging to check what's actually happening. BTW. AnymalsProfile(
                user = user,
                locale = ProfileData["locale"]
                        ) - no need to pass user.id - just user

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it didn't like cleaned_data. It now works using the following:

```
def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        data = AnymalsProfile(user=user)
        data.locale = form.data["locale"]
        data.save()
```

Thanks @dmitko for the code and the support. keep it up!

Comment: I've tried doing as you have, but have got this tricky error, can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695713/django-reg-extend-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-o